Conditionally set AtomicReference
I would like to conditionally and atomically update (or set if the current is empty) an AtomicReference based on a Predicate on the current value.
I was hoping that something like this existed:
/**
* Updates the value to the result of the function, unless result of function is null.
* The function is applied with the current value as its first argument.
* Concurrent callers while this method is executing will continue to see the existing
* current value.
*/
V conditionallyUpdate(UnaryOperator<V> function)

and usage would be something like this:
V getNonExpiredValue() {
  return myAtomicRef.conditionallyUpdate( existingVal -> {
    if (existingVal == null) {
      return getNewVal();
    }
    if (existingVal.isExpired()) {
      return getNewVal();
    }
    return null;  // do nothing, the existing value is fine!
  });
}

I'm aware that this has a smell of ConcurrentMap but I only have a single value.

I would do a simple retrieval, check the #isExpired, and if it is expired, do a compare-and-swap (#compareAndExchange(expected, newValue)) with a new value (using the "old value" as our "expected value"). This way, if someone else already set the atomic while we attempted an update, we won't overwrite it, and will receive the proper one instead.

This looks easy enough to build out of updateAndGet():
return myAtomicRef.updateAndGet(oldValue -> {
  V newValue = function.apply(oldValue);
  return (newValue == null) ? oldValue : newValue;
});


You can make use of method getAndUpdate of AtomicReference. This would look like:
atomicRef.getAndUpdate( existingVal -> {
    if (existingVal == null) {
      return getNewVal();
    }
    if (existingVal.isExpired()) {
      return getNewVal();
    }
    return existingVal;  // keep the existing value since it is fine, returning null would set the atomic ref to null
});

Also note that javadoc of that method says that

The function should be side-effect-free, since it may be re-applied when attempted updates fail due to contention among threads

This also means the update method should not be too costly (time- and resource-wise).

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think getAndUpdate /  updateAndGet are atomic operations, although the actual setting of the new value is. This means that 'updateFunction' may be called by multiple threads concurrently. This is what I wanted to avoid.

@peterh What makes you believe these are not atomic where the javadoc states "Atomically updates (with memory effects as specified by {@link VarHandle#compareAndSet}) the current value with the results of applying the given function"? If you don't want the update function be called multiple times and/or concurrently you should revise your question. I can't read that from your posted question.

If you don't ever want updateFunction to be called concurrently, then AtomicReference doesn't help you at all.
